# PayPal IPN Simulator not working

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to send an Instant Payment Notification (IPN) to my server using Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator on Paypal Developer site.

I have been searching all over the internet and I found a site which allows to test the ipn http://samples.geekality.net/ipn/ 
when I use this url http://samples.geekality.net/ipn/listener.php in IPN simulator it shows me the data on this sample site but when I use my own site's url which is something like this http://example.com/appointments/payment/notify it just doesn't work I am sending an mail function using to my email something like this:

```
mail('example@example.com', 'notify action performed', http_build_query($_REQUEST));
```

when I access this url directly it works and send me an email but doesn't work with ipn simulator.

FYI: Return/Cancel url works fine.

Q: Am I doing something wrong? And How can I solve it?

Please let me know if this is a possible duplicate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried to reproduce your issue, but everything seems to work fine. Maybe the email was sent in the spam folder, or maybe you're server is having problems with the `mail()` function

Comment: mail() function works fine as mentioned in the question when I access the url directly it works and send me an email directly to inbox not in span also the span folder is empty

Comment: Then, maybee your server firewall is blocking HTTP POST request messages from PayPal. Check your access log and error log to see if you find something.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem.  I was actually able to get the IPN simulator to work on testing my IPN listener a few times.  Each time I was learning from the errors.  Once I thought things should be working again I was getting an "Internal Server Error".  At first I thought this was my server returning 500, but the logs showed Paypal wasn't even trying to talk to my server.

Since you now have to login to use the IPN simulator, I resolved this issue by logging out and back in with a different account (I happen to have a few already) and it started working again.

Hopefully this helps someone else having this issue.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for sharing your experience, sure it might help someone.